# How to turn vue font awesome icon into a javascript prop?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

i'm trying to turn:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'home']" />
```

into a Javascript prop. I have a navigation menu i'm building and each nav item has a different icon. I've read both the font awesome/vue documentation and i'm still confused.

I have a component for the navigation as a whole, then a child component for a flexible link (a nav item with a dropdown)

Here's a snippet of the html from a single navigation item:

```
<side-nav-flexible-link linkName="Games">
    <li><a href="#">New Leaf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pocket Camp</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Horizons</a></li>
  </side-nav-flexible-link>
```

Html for a single dropdown link:

```
<template><li>
<div class="icon_link" @click="clickArrow">
  <a href="#">
    <font-awesome-icon class="icon" :icon="['fas', 'plug']" />
    <span class="link_name">{{ linkName }}</span>
  </a>

  <font-awesome-icon
    class="icon"
    :icon="['fas', 'chevron-down']"
  />
</div>

<ul v-show="isOpen" class="sub-menu">
  <slot />
</ul>
```

My javascript so far:

```js
<script>
export default ({
  props: {
    linkName: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Unnamed'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clickArrow () {
      if (this.isOpen === true) {
        this.isOpen = false
      } else {
        this.isOpen = true
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `icon` prop under `props`:

```js
// SideNavFlexibleLink.vue
export default {
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: 'plug'
    }
  }
}
```

And bind that in your link's template to the `font-awesome-icon`:

```html
// SideNavFlexibleLink.vue
<font-awesome-icon class="icon" :icon="['fas', icon]" />
```

Then you could pass in the icon name as needed:

```html
// App.vue
<side-nav-flexible-link linkName="Games" icon="home">
```

Comment: its a start, should prob be `type: [String,Array]`, with `default: undefined`, then a v-if on the icon plus `:icon="typeof icon === 'string' ? ['fas', icon] : icon"`, just sayin